Build specific website (kind of a portfolio) - which tools should I use?
Sorry if my English is not really good.
I want to build a Web App (Physiotherapist portfolio Web App). The Web App, it is kind-off a Portfolio but has a lot of extra functionalities not associated to a simple Portfolio.
The Portfolio would have the next things.

CRM functionalities. Like a Blog, the Admin/Owner of the Portfolio could post entries, edit posts, organize posts, galleries, automatic publishing and calendar.
Newsletter functionalities. Like a newsletter where you could post notices about, like and editorial
Social Media functionalities. There would be three types of user roles, client (user signed-up and logged-up), user (non-signed-up user or users that are not logged-up). Registered and Logged users would have a profile and modify some aspects. The non-register/logged can make comments, but does not have a profile. ETC ETC, this doesn't matter
E-commerce functionalities. Users would be able to buy services from the 'portfolio', request appointment to the Physiotherapist, buy some bonuses or offers like 5 appointments for less price, etc, etc.

Now as you can see. It a really specific Web App, but I do not know what is the best option. By the way I have a lot of programming skills on Web Apps. I guess the options are:

Use a CMS platform. But shopping would be difficult to implement
Use a E-commerce platform. But blog, portfolio, newsletter system would be difficult to implement
Build my own Web on Springboot (Java). Just start by 0. But as you can see this app could take me 5 or 6 months to build all this. BBDD, APIS, SECURITY, Front-END, etc etc.

Anyone have any suggestions here? I would be grateful to see someone to respond to this question.


Use a CMS platform. But shopping would be difficult to implement

Your question comes from an invalid idea - I don't know what made you think that. CMSes actually have very commonly used e-commerce plugins. For instance, WordPress has WooCommerce that I would say is the best free combination. Joomla has VirtueMart, although Joomla is much more clunky in general. Etc.
Most of these extensions don't even require too much coding to bridge your blog/CMS and the store. Perhaps some styling changes if you'll use a non-default theme. Maybe some JavaScript conflictr resolutions at worst. Other than that, they integrate really well.
And they have all the features that are needed within a modern store - integrations with payment providers, mailing, cart, tracking, etc.

I do not know how to thanks you this response. It solves me everything I was doubting. Also It gives me the path to follow (and no to built a complex sprinboot app which would take me months, even years. Thanks you a lot!

Glad it helped!
